# Enabling cascading deletes on either side of a join table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-delete, cascade, knex.js

I have one `User` model with a primary key of `id`. I am currently modeling Supervisor > User relationships with a join table of sorts called `user_supervisors` which has only two columns, `user_id` and `supervisor_id`, both of which are foreign keys referencing the primary key of `User` record.

Is it possible that when I delete a user (whether they are a supervisor or not), any records containing that user in the `user_supervisors` table is also deleted?

I have been attempting to make use of sql server's cascading deletes but it doesn't seem to be possible to have cascading deletes on both the user_id and supervisor_id foreign keys at the same time. I always encounter a message along the lines of:

> Knex:warning - migration failed with error: CREATE TABLE [user_supervisors] ([user_id] int, [supervisor_id] int, CONSTRAINT [user_supervisors_pkey] PRIMARY KEY ([user_id], [supervisor_id]), CONSTRAINT [user_supervisors_user_id_foreign] FOREIGN KEY ([user_id]) REFERENCES [users] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT [user_supervisors_supervisor_id_foreign] FOREIGN KEY ([supervisor_id]) REFERENCES [users] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE) - Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

For the record I am using [knex](http://knexjs.org/) to run my database migrations
Below is the SQL used when creating each table mentioned above:

```
CREATE TABLE [users] 
(
    [id] int identity(1,1) not null primary key
    , [created_at] datetime
    , [updated_at] datetime
    , [email] nvarchar(255) not null
    , [first_name] nvarchar(255)
    , [last_name] nvarchar(255)
    , [password] nvarchar(255) not null
    , [company_id] int
    , CONSTRAINT [users_email_unique] UNIQUE ([email])
    , CONSTRAINT [users_company_id_foreign] FOREIGN KEY ([company_id]) REFERENCES [companies] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE [user_supervisors] 
(
    [user_id] int
    , [supervisor_id] int
    , CONSTRAINT [user_supervisors_pkey] PRIMARY KEY ([user_id], [supervisor_id])
    , CONSTRAINT [user_supervisors_user_id_foreign] FOREIGN KEY ([user_id]) REFERENCES [users] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
    , CONSTRAINT [user_supervisors_supervisor_id_foreign] FOREIGN KEY ([supervisor_id]) REFERENCES [users] ([id])
)
```

Comment: Can you share the ddl for the two base tables as well?

Comment: **[Foreign Keys with cascade delete](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)**

Comment: @SeanLange, the post has been updated

Comment: Your update is a little mixed up I think. You posted the user_supervisors again, but the foreign key is a little different. But on a different topic you should NEVER EVER EVER be storing passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed ALWAYS. Storing passwords in plain text can potentially be criminal in some states. Don't do this, learn how to handle passwords with encryption correctly.

Comment: @SeanLange lol don't worry man that's all handled pre-write to the db. Back on subject however, the update looks good to me, each line is the SQL generated for the User and UserSupervisor tables respectively. If there is anything else you need lemme know, but thanks for your time regardless.

Comment: I couldn't read your table script as posted because it was just a wall of text. Once I added some formatting it becomes immediately clear what the problem is. Did you try creating these tables with adding the second "ON DELETE CASCADE"? If you did you would get an error. Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'user_supervisors_supervisor_id_foreign' on table 'user_supervisors' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. This is because logically you could create an circular reference of cascading deletes. Perhaps you should reconsider your architecture a bit here.

Comment: You might want to consider a trigger in this situation. Or create a delete stored procedure that will delete rows from this table when you delete a user.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support multiple cascade paths. Are you sure the `user_supervisors` table is the right model? Do you really need to support that a user can have multiple supervisors?